# Leaked Object NSDate: ResumeTimer & PauseTimer

Tags: iphone

Tested app in Instrumens for memory leak getting multiple leaks for using multiple times pauseTimer and resumeTimer.

Defined in m file

```
NSDate *pauseStart, *previousFireDate;

-(void)pauseTimer{
pauseStart = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] retain];
previousFireDate = [[timer fireDate] retain];
[timer setFireDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}

  -(void)resumeTimer{
float pauseTime = -1*[pauseStart timeIntervalSinceNow];
//[timer setFireDate:[previousFireDate initWithTimeInterval:pauseTime sinceDate:previousFireDate]];
[timer setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:pauseTime sinceDate:previousFireDate]];
}
```

how to fix this memory leak for pauseTimer and resumeTimer. User can use PauseTimer and resumeTimer multiple times.

Appreciate help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are retaining the values for `pauseStart` and `previousFireDate` each time the `pauseTimer` method is fired. You need to release the previous values before retaining the new values in order to avoid a memory leak.

Easiest solution is to create two retained properties for those values (possibly in a class extension), so when you set new values, the release is handled for you. (Just don't forget to release the values in your dealloc method to also avoid leaks.)

Comment: i have released pauseStart and previousFireDate in the alloc method now getting leak for UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent how to fix this one now

Comment: -(void)dealloc
{
[audioPlayer release];   
[pauseStart release];
[previousFireDate release];
[super dealloc];
}

Comment: and you're setting the property values using their setters? self.pauseStart = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]; self.previousFireDate = [timer fireDate];

Comment: @property (nonatomic, assign) NSDate *pauseStart,*previousFireDate;@synthesize pauseStart,previousFireDate;-(void)pauseTimer{   
self.pauseStart = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]; self.previousFireDate = [timer fireDate];[timer setFireDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];}-(void)resumeTimer{float pauseTime = -1*[pauseStart timeIntervalSinceNow];[timer setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:pauseTime sinceDate:previousFireDate]];}now app crashes[__NSDate timeIntervalSinceNow]: message sent to deallocated instance

Comment: @ property (nonatomic, assign) needs to be: @ property (nonatomic, retain)

Comment: yeah just few seconds ago i realized it. i changed it now it is working fine.

Comment: Thanks so much for help. Appreciate it so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSTimer's `isValid` property and `invalidate` method.

```
-(void)pauseTimer
{
    if ( !timer.isValid )
        return;

    // remember your fire date

    [timer invalidate];
}

-(void)resumeTimer
{
    if ( timer.isValid )
        return;

    // schedule your timer to new date
    // release old date
}
```